# Ingress ip whitelisting on load balancer - aws k8s

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to use the Security group to allow https traffic only from a particular IP. I have created the Ingress Service and resource. (ref: [NGINX Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws)

I tried configuring below on Ingress Service.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: {cert}
    # the backend instances are HTTP
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
    # Map port 443
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: {SG Allowing ingres from IP}
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: http
```

I tried below on resource as well.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: {SG Allowing ingres from IP}
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "IP"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
```

What am I missing?

I see auto-generated SG on load balancer which allows all inbound traffic. But I'm not sure if its created by service or resource. And if its ok to edit that directly.

**Update:**
Autogenerated SG
[image]

I added another SG which limits IP for ingress but doesn't get applied.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the access to lax or too strict?

Comment: @FrankYuchengGu too lax. Allows all inbound access with http/https. I want to IP restrict it. I added SG with the rule and applied with above annotations but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Has the SG been correctly associated with the ELB? Does it work if you manually add the SG to ELB?

Comment: The sg I see on elb I didn’t configure anywhere. It seems it’s auto generated by nginx controller(service) or resource from above. I added extra SG with IP whitelist but doesn’t seem to be working

Comment: @FrankYuchengGu So I updated auto-generated SG with IP whitelist ingress and it works. Involves manual intervention. :( Also the request stays in connecting forever it should receive Connection refused may be

Comment: If this is the only resource for which requests are coming in, you should try to implement the IP filtering at the subnet level using NACL, rather than trying to implement it at the instance level using SGs. Is this an options?

Comment: @FrankYuchengGu yah it seems like bug reported on the same issue. Dojo for manny ally for now . Fahbnjs

Answer (score 0):

In your service definition of ingress add the following section

```
spec:
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: //add this section
    - 127.0.0.1/32
    - 28.50.20.12/31
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The default behavior is that when you don't specify `loadBalancerSourceRanges` it default into 0/0

Hope this helps.